# How can I combine material ui mini variant drawer and code from dark theme switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, darkmode

I take the example code from the mui mini variant drawer (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/ and a code for a dark/light theme switch and unfortunately the switch doesn't do a thing:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { 
    useState, 
    }  from 'react';
import { Switch } from "@material-ui/core";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));


const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function MiniDrawer() {
  // const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("dark");
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: "dark",
      background: {
        default: "hsl(230, 8%, 71%)"
      },
      color:"#FFFFFF"
    }
  });
  
  const lightTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: "light",
      background: {
        default: "hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"
      }
    }
  });
  // const selectedTheme = mode === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
  const selectedtheme = mode === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
 

   return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={selectedtheme}>
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open} style={{ background: '#2E3B55' }}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 5,
              ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          {/* Box helps to only right-flush Dark/Bright Button */}
            <Box display='flex' flexGrow={1}>
                
                {/* <Assessment className={classes.icon} /> */}
                <Typography variant ="h6" noWrap component="div" >
                    Headline in Appbar
                </Typography>
            
            </Box>
            <Switch onChange={() => setMode(mode === "dark" ? "dark" : "light")} />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {selectedtheme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
      Example Text in page
      </Box>
    </Box>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

I assume that my selectedtheme and the prescribed theme don't work together.
I removed the line

```
const theme = useTheme();
```

in the function MiniDrawer. That didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in the example above ThemeProvider and createTheme are loaded from "@material-ui/core/styles". To load them from '@mui/material/styles' helps to get the dark mode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).